# EWS Autodiscover unacceptable timeout

Tags: exchangewebservices

If I do the following

```
var autodiscoverService = new AutodiscoverService{
    // Timeout = 100,  // Appears to have no impact
    EnableScpLookup = false,
    RedirectionUrlValidationCallback =
        delegate { return true; },
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    TraceEnabled = true,
    TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All,
    TraceListener = listener,
    Credentials =
        new WebCredentials("billg@microsoft.com", "anything", null)
};
```

The very first trace message I get is:

```
<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="19" Time="2012-07-06 16:05:09Z">
   Determining which endpoints are enabled for host microsoft.com
</Trace>
```

Note the time (:09).  The next event is ~40 seconds later:

```
<Trace Tag="AutodiscoverConfiguration" Tid="19" Time="2012-07-06 16:05:51Z">
   Determining which endpoints are enabled for host autodiscover.microsoft.com
</Trace>
```

Quickly thereafter (as expected, auth fails).

If I use the Exchange connectivity tester at https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/, even if I use invalid auth info I get answers back almost immediately.

I don't have a valid MS account to test with, but I asked one person to test it and they saw the same 40 second timeout even with their valid username/pw.

I *swear* just a few weeks ago I tested this and did not see any problems with Microsoft's autodiscover setup; I suspect something has changed recently.

While this question uses microsoft.com as an example, I'm afraid that there may be other poorly configured Exchange setups that will give this same delay and that would suck for my users.

I've tried setting `autodiscoverService.Timeout = 100` and that didn't help.

Is there any way to have more fine grained control of EWS's autodiscover functionality?

How else can I address/work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that the domain "microsoft.com" does not implement autodiscover in the expected manor. And as a result the autodiscover service tries every possible endpoint and eventually fails out.

I tried your code with my email address/credentials and issued a GetUserSettings request based on the example MS provides at [AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.autodiscover.autodiscoverservice.getusersettings%28v=exchg.80%29).

I have both onprem Exchange and Office 365 to test with and onprem Exchange finished in about 2 seconds and Office 365 took 7 seconds start to finish.

I then changed my code to use the email address/credentials you used and I saw the same 40 timeout.

Have you tried testing this against another domain beside microsoft.com?